# How should I rewrite this sentence to use the passive voice?

Tags: passive-voice

If I were to rewrite the following sentence using the passive voice, how should I rewrite it?

> That university has English classes for people whose native language is not English.

I thought to the following sentence, but I was wondering if I could use something else instead of *given*.

> English classes for people whose native language is not English are given from that university.

As side question, is *programme* more appropriate in this case, or is *classes* a better word?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In the US we typically say that classes are *offered* rather than *given*

The preposition will be *by* or *at*, not *from*.

What is offered is more likely to be *courses* than *classes*. *Classes* tends to be used more in secondary-school or non-academic contexts.

So:

> English courses for people whose native language is not English are offered by that university.

**But note**: the passive is awkward in this instance. Other things being equal, English prefers to put “heavy” constituents—those with many words—at the end of a sentence rather than the beginning or middle, because the syntactic structure is most visible when the primary constituents are close together at the front. Compare the structures for the passive and active sentences:

> [***Subj*** <sub><sup>English courses</sup></sub> *MinAdj*  <sub><sup>for people whose native language is not English</sup></sub>] [***Verb*** <sub><sup>are offered</sup></sub>] [***MajAdj*** <sub><sup>by that university.</sup></sub>]
>
> [***Subj*** <sub><sup>That university</sup></sub>] [***Verb*** <sub><sup>offers</sup></sub>] [***DirObj*** <sub><sup>English courses</sup></sub> *MinAdj* <sub><sup>for people whose native language is not English.</sup></sub>]

In the passive sentence, that's a long run from Subject to Verb. In this case you could get around this by moving the “minor” adjunct to the end:

> English courses are offered by that university for people whose native language is not English.
>
> [***Subj*** <sub><sup>English courses</sup></sub>] [***Verb*** <sub><sup>are offered</sup></sub>] [***MajAdj*** <sub><sup>by that university</sup></sub>] [*MinAdj* <sub><sup>for people whose native language is not English.</sup></sub>]

Comment: In the third form, the *MinAdj* phrase is in position to modify *university* rather than *courses*.

Comment: @jwpat7  Quite so; but in context few would read it in that sense; in fact, it would probably be read as modifying *offer*! ... But those are the pitfalls of "information packaging". Me, I'd just go with the active voice here.

Comment: As side question, what does the [New York University](http://www.nyu.edu/its/classes/) site mean, when it says _classes_?

Comment: @kiamlaluno Note that it is capitalized: *NYU Classes* is a "learning management system" - a portal to instructional resources which is replacing the existing *Blackboard* system. It serves as a supplement to or replacement for classroom instruction. .. *Class* and *course* are both used in US college parlance, but *course* is more often employed for the semester-long unit of instruction, while *class* is more often used to designate a session or meeting of a *course*.